# SED- Change column from lower to upper case based on 2 conditions from script

Tags: regex, linux, sed, posix

I have to change column "name" from lower to upper case based on the condition that the sport column is either shooting or judo.

So far, I have the following code provided by anubhava works in the terminal, but not inside the script:

`sed -E 's/^([^,]*,)([^,]+)((,[^,]*){5},(shooting|judo),)/\1\U\2\L\3/'`

Some input:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
388896171,Abdelraouf Benguit,ALG,male,1985-07-03,1.83,90,judo,0,0,0,
285603057,Abderrahmane Mansouri,ALG,male,1995-01-13,1.72,66,cycling,0,0,0,
545134894,Abderrahmane Meziane,ALG,male,1994-03-07,1.68,62,football,0,0,0,
969824503,Abdullah Alrashidi,IOA,male,1963-08-21,1.83,84,shooting,0,0,1,
897549624,Abdullah Hel Baki,BAN,male,1989-08-01,,,shooting,0,0,0,
153457,Abdullahi Shehu,NGR,male,1993-03-12,1.70,,football,0,0,1,
```

Expected output:

```
    id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
    388896171,ABDELRAOUF BENGUIT,ALG,male,1985-07-03,1.83,90,judo,0,0,0,
    285603057,Abderrahmane Mansouri,ALG,male,1995-01-13,1.72,66,cycling,0,0,0,
    545134894,Abderrahmane Meziane,ALG,male,1994-03-07,1.68,62,football,0,0,0,
    969824503,ABDULLAH ALRASHIDI,IOA,male,1963-08-21,1.83,84,shooting,0,0,1,
    897549624,ABDULLAH HEL BAKI,BAN,male,1989-08-01,,,shooting,0,0,0,
    153457,Abdullahi Shehu,NGR,male,1993-03-12,1.70,,football,0,0,1,
```

This code will be going into a script and executed with sed -f. It needs to be with sed.

The script is basically the following lines:

```
s/ESP/Spain/g
s/DEN/Denmark/g
s/NED/netherlands/g
s/^([^,]*,)([^,]+)((,[^,]*){5},(shooting|judo),)/\1\U\2\L\3/
/[0],[0],[0],$/d
1 c id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
```

And I'm calling the script like this:

```
$ sed -f script3_3.sed athletesv22.csv
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is not the right tool for this. You should consider `awk`.

You may use a `awk` solution like this:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR > 1 && $8 ~ /^(shooting|judo)$/ {
$2 = toupper($2)} 1' file.csv

id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
388896171,ABDELRAOUF BENGUIT,ALG,male,1985-07-03,1.83,90,judo,0,0,0,
285603057,Abderrahmane Mansouri,ALG,male,1995-01-13,1.72,66,cycling,0,0,0,
545134894,Abderrahmane Meziane,ALG,male,1994-03-07,1.68,62,football,0,0,0,
969824503,ABDULLAH ALRASHIDI,IOA,male,1963-08-21,1.83,84,shooting,0,0,1,
897549624,ABDULLAH HEL BAKI,BAN,male,1989-08-01,,,shooting,0,0,0,
153457,Abdullahi Shehu,NGR,male,1993-03-12,1.70,,football,0,0,1,
```

To save changes inline to input file use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
NR > 1 && $8 ~ /^(shooting|judo)$/ {$2 = toupper($2)} 1' file.csv
```

Or if you don't have `gnu-awk` then use:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR > 1 && $8 ~ /^(shooting|judo)$/ {
$2 = toupper($2)} 1' file.csv > _tmp_ && mv _tmp_ file.csv
```

---

This `gnu-sed` solution should work for you:

```sh
sed -E 's/^([^,]*,)([^,]+)((,[^,]*){5},(shooting|judo),)/\1\U\2\L\3/' file.csv

id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
388896171,ABDELRAOUF BENGUIT,alg,male,1985-07-03,1.83,90,judo,0,0,0,
285603057,Abderrahmane Mansouri,ALG,male,1995-01-13,1.72,66,cycling,0,0,0,
545134894,Abderrahmane Meziane,ALG,male,1994-03-07,1.68,62,football,0,0,0,
969824503,ABDULLAH ALRASHIDI,ioa,male,1963-08-21,1.83,84,shooting,0,0,1,
897549624,ABDULLAH HEL BAKI,ban,male,1989-08-01,,,shooting,0,0,0,
153457,Abdullahi Shehu,NGR,male,1993-03-12,1.70,,football,0,0,1,
```

[Working Demo](https://ideone.com/yM92Hn)

Comment: Sorry but it needs to be resolved with sed. Any way to do it?

Comment: Why is that? Any unix system has `awk` available like `sed`. Use the right tool

Comment: @JoseAntonioPiedehierroArias if you want to prohibit `awk` usage why are using `awk` tag?

Comment: Because I am not allowed to use AWK, basically. I'm learning sed from scratch and I need to acomplish X knowledge before using AWK for basically, everything.

Comment: You are right Daweo, my bad. Typo error

Comment: I does not seem to be working inside the script .sed

Comment: The thing is how I do the sed -E inside the script? because in the prompt (where it's working) I'm calling sed -f because the script does other things such as substitutions or deletings of rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243999/discussion-between-jose-antonio-piedehierro-arias-and-anubhava).